# Proliant Support Pack and Ubuntu on older HP Proliants

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant

We have a couple of oldish HP Proliant servers -- one DL385 G1 and one DL360 G5, to be exact -- that we'd like to upgrade from CentOS 5 to Ubuntu LucidLynx. The problem is that HP doesn't offer Ubuntu Proliant Support Packs for these particular models.

Would you upgrade regardless, skipping the PSPs altogether?

Are there alternative hardware monitoring tools that would match the functionality of the PSPs?

Is there a hack to install the PSP RPMs on an Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with the Proliant servies, we just received our DL360 a few days ago.

I went to [HPs Software Delivery Repository](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/), read through the [getting started](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/getting_started.html) guide and read the [FAQ](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/faq.html) and ended up having additional sources.list files with allowed me to simply run `aptitude install hp-health hp-snmp-agents`.

Prior running `bootstrap.sh` I had to install the `lsb-release` package and then `lib32gcc1` because I've installed Lenny amd64 (but that's covered in the FAQ).

The command I ran was: `sh bootstrap.sh ProLiantSupportPack`

Comment: Addendum: In my case, I also had to run hpsnmpconfig and then /etc/init.d/hp-snmp-agents start to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

just to update your mental image

- we use 2 oldies (DL360 G4) more than 3 years.
- In the begin we had there Fedora Linux (current release at the time).
- At some point we moved to OpenSuse runnig Xen (as the host) with 2 virtual machines running CentOS 5.3.
- The machines use 5 internal disks (1 + 2 x RAID1(2disc))
- the machines use external SAN (MSA 2000f) connected by optical HBA
- We never used no HW drivers nor any other HP delivered custom SW
- no problems encountered

Answer (score 0):

Well there's nothing wrong just using the standard code, you'll be missing a few drivers with extra prefailure warnings etc. but nothing functional really. That said if you have the time there's no harm just giving it a go with the PSP, worst comes to worst it's a reinstall so maybe try it as soon as you've done the basic install. I'm surprised the G5 isn't supported, there's not that much difference from a hardware perspective between that and the G6 bar the processor and memory types.

Comment: The entire chipset is different in the G6.  New processor family (and socket, I believe), memory, and RAID controller (Smart Array P410).

Comment: I mentioned the processor and memory but nothing in the PSP will stop the base OS from using these resources properly and the P410 family is backwardly compatible with the P400 family so it's work - you'll be missing a few of the new tricks as I mention in my response but it'll probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the link now, but I have seen people report that they were able to install the PSP on Debian/Ubuntu systems.  I know that part of the process was running the .rpm through alien to convert it to a .deb package.  Try that and see where that gets you.

I personally recommend installing the PSP for the benefits of the improved hardware support (drivers, and notification), as well as the Systems Management Homepage (SMH).  If you have SNMP monitoring in your environment, it should also improve your system's visibility.